# Declare inside if condition showing syntax error - MYSQL Triggers

Tags: mysql

I try to update some columns using trigger before insert

```
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_p_posts_places;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_p_posts_places BEFORE
INSERT
ON
    `p_posts` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN      
    DECLARE
        p_post_group_id_ int;
    SELECT
        `p_post_subgroup`.`p_post_group_id`
    INTO
        p_post_group_id_
    FROM
        `p_post_subgroup`
    WHERE
        `p_post_subgroup`.`p_post_subgroup_id` = NEW.p_post_subgroup_id;
        IF(p_post_group_id_ = 5) THEN
        BEGIN
        DECLARE
            place1_id_ int;
            place2_id_ int;
            place3_id_ int;
            place4_id_ int;
            place5_id_ int;
        SELECT
            `Places`.`place1_id`,
            `Places`.`place2_id`,
            `Places`.`place3_id`,
            `Places`.`place4_id`,
            `Places`.`place5_id`
        INTO
            place1_id_, place2_id_, place3_id_, place4_id_, place5_id_
        FROM
            `Places`
        WHERE
            `Places`.`place5_id` = NEW.p_post_place_id LIMIT 1;
    SET NEW.place5_id = place5_id_;
    SET NEW.place1_id = place1_id_;
    SET NEW.place2_id = place2_id_;
    SET NEW.place3_id = place3_id_;
    SET NEW.place4_id = place4_id_;
    END $$
    ELSE
SET NEW.place5_id = NULL;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It's showing some syntax errors.

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE
place1_id_ int;
place2_id_ int;
' at line 20**

Comment: Declared variables have to be immediately after the BEGIN and you have more begins than you need.

Comment: I updated my query. Same error.

Comment: Your first end should be terminated by ; (semi-colon) not $$ and every variable needs a DECLARE

Comment: you have `END $$` inside your code. It should be used only once at the end before `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: In DECLARE the variables must be separated with `,`, not with `;`.

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you for your suggestions. It's working fine.

Comment: @Alex thank you for your suggestions. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working trigger. I tested creating it on MySQL 5.7.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_p_posts_places BEFORE INSERT ON `p_posts`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN      
    -- all declarations must be before any other statements
    DECLARE p_post_group_id_, place1_id_, place2_id_, place3_id_,
        place4_id_, place5_id_ int;
    SELECT
        `p_post_subgroup`.`p_post_group_id`
    INTO
        p_post_group_id_
    FROM
        `p_post_subgroup`
    WHERE
        `p_post_subgroup`.`p_post_subgroup_id` = NEW.p_post_subgroup_id;
    IF(p_post_group_id_ = 5) THEN
        SELECT
            `Places`.`place1_id`,
            `Places`.`place2_id`,
            `Places`.`place3_id`,
            `Places`.`place4_id`,
            `Places`.`place5_id`
        INTO
            place1_id_, place2_id_, place3_id_, place4_id_, place5_id_
        FROM
            `Places`
        WHERE
            `Places`.`place5_id` = NEW.p_post_place_id LIMIT 1;
        SET NEW.place5_id = place5_id_;
        SET NEW.place1_id = place1_id_;
        SET NEW.place2_id = place2_id_;
        SET NEW.place3_id = place3_id_;
        SET NEW.place4_id = place4_id_;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.place5_id = NULL;
    END IF;
END $$
```

You can use one `DECLARE` for multiple local variables, but you must do like `var1, var2, var3, ... int`. In other words, name the type only once at the end. See documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html

No need for the `BEGIN..END` inside the `IF` and definitely do not use `$$` until after the last `END` because that will terminate the parser's interpretation of your whole CREATE TRIGGER statement before it's complete.